# Java language is inaccurate for calculations?

Tags: java

I tried the following `for` loop:

```
for(double i = 0.0; i<=0.001; i+=0.0001)
    System.out.println(i);
```

And I get the following output:

> 0.0
>   1.0E-4
>   2.0E-4
>   3.0000000000000003E-4
>   4.0E-4
>   5.0E-4
>   6.000000000000001E-4
>   7.000000000000001E-4
>   8.000000000000001E-4
>   9.000000000000002E-4

My questions are:

- How do these extra `.000000000000001`s come?
- Will these extra numbers always come, or is there some problem in my code?
- Do these errors occur only in the Java language, or any other programming languages too?
- Is `double` suitable for `for` loops?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of IEEE 754 :p

Comment: this is actually not the fault of java, but comes from the approximative representation of decimal fractions in IEEE floating points

Comment: *"Java language is inaccurate for calculations?"* > **No**. *"Float/Double in any language is inaccurate for calculations?"* > **Yes**. If you want fixed precision, use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: @TT. What about my other questions?

Comment: I would have closed it, but these are 4 questions, and not all of them are answered in [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). But the only open question is the last one. Regarding that: You should write such a loop as `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { double d = i * 0.0001; ... }` to avoid an **accumulation** of errors. But it will not circumvent the inherent limited precision that is described in the other answer.

Comment: @fge What is the full form of IEEE? I searched the net, but found something like Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers. I guess that's not what you mean...?

Comment: And another side note: People are (IMHO **far** too) quick with recommending `BigDecimal`. It has its own issues, and is cumbersome to use. In most cases, the limited precision of `double` simply does not matter, and **if** you think that it matters, you should clearly explain **why** - then it's possible to judge whether `BigDecimal` really makes sense.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, not all numbers can be represented exactly in [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

> For example, the decimal number 0.1 is not representable in binary
>   floating-point of any finite precision; the exact binary
>   representation would have a "1100" sequence continuing endlessly:
>
> e = −4; s = 1100110011001100110011001100110011..., where, as
>   previously, s is the significand and e is the exponent.
>
> When rounded to 24 bits this becomes
>
> e = −4; s = 110011001100110011001101, which is actually
>   0.100000001490116119384765625 in decimal.

Comment: Does anyone knows where strictfp keyword stands here?

Comment: See this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp)

Comment: thx, oh that bad http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Try using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), here is my example code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {

    private static final BigDecimal UPPER_LIMIT = new BigDecimal(0.001);
    private static final BigDecimal STEPS = new BigDecimal(0.0001);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.ZERO; i.compareTo(UPPER_LIMIT) != 1; i = i.add(STEPS)){
            System.out.printf("%.4f\n", i);
        }

    }

}
```

And the output is:

```
0.0000
0.0001
0.0002
0.0003
0.0004
0.0005
0.0006
0.0007
0.0008
0.0009
```

p.s. I didnt spent time for memory management and other detail, should be much more heavy process than using primitives